# Error, when build Mediapipe graph for iOS using bazel

Tags: ios, bazel, mediapipe

I cloned official mediapipe repository and tried to build examples for iOS, accordingly instructions. But when I build any example I got linking error.

**For Intel iMac logs:**

```
ERROR: /Users/artemsokolovskiy/mediapipe0.10.1/mediapipe/mediapipe/graphs/face_detection/BUILD:56:23: Linking mediapipe/graphs/face_detection/face_detection_mobile_cpu_binary_graph_text_to_binary_graph [for tool] failed: (Exit 1): cc_wrapper.sh failed: error executing command (from target //mediapipe/graphs/face_detection:face_detection_mobile_cpu_binary_graph_text_to_binary_graph)
(cd /private/var/tmp/_bazel_artemsokolovskiy/8ec7566841d7814b73c1b8ae8937638c/sandbox/darwin-sandbox/1944/execroot/mediapipe && 
exec env - 
APPLE_SDK_PLATFORM=MacOSX 
APPLE_SDK_VERSION_OVERRIDE=13.1 
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin 
XCODE_VERSION_OVERRIDE=14.2.0.14C18 
ZERO_AR_DATE=1 
external/local_config_cc/cc_wrapper.sh @bazel-out/darwin-opt-exec-50AE0418-ST-0d1fe7b00ffe/bin/mediapipe/graphs/face_detection/face_detection_mobile_cpu_binary_graph_text_to_binary_graph-2.params)
Configuration: e9670154d5af08fa52d86e0762a1381506511f62455c5fc774c6bd94d6701f1f
Execution platform: @local_execution_config_platform//:platform

Use --sandbox_debug to see verbose messages from the sandbox and retain the sandbox build root for debugging
stderr (/private/var/tmp/_bazel_artemsokolovskiy/8ec7566841d7814b73c1b8ae8937638c/execroot/mediapipe/bazel-out/_tmp/actions/stderr-326) 1953000 exceeds maximum size of --experimental_ui_max_stdouterr_bytes=1048576 bytes; skipping
Target //mediapipe/examples/ios/facedetectioncpu:FaceDetectionCpuApp failed to build
INFO: Elapsed time: 12.650s, Critical Path: 12.39s
INFO: 200 processes: 3 internal, 197 darwin-sandbox.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

**For Mac mini M1 logs:**

```
ERROR: /Users/timuribragimov/mediapipev0.10.1/mediapipe/mediapipe/graphs/face_detection/BUILD:56:23: Linking mediapipe/graphs/face_detection/face_detection_mobile_cpu_binary_graph_text_to_binary_graph [for tool] failed: (Exit 1): cc_wrapper.sh failed: error executing command (from target //mediapipe/graphs/face_detection:face_detection_mobile_cpu_binary_graph_text_to_binary_graph)
(cd /private/var/tmp/_bazel_timuribragimov/fedbca33a62f845c3a501d6b33f83488/sandbox/darwin-sandbox/1641/execroot/mediapipe && 
exec env - 
APPLE_SDK_PLATFORM=MacOSX 
APPLE_SDK_VERSION_OVERRIDE=13.1 
PATH=/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.8/bin:/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin 
XCODE_VERSION_OVERRIDE=14.2.0.14C18 
ZERO_AR_DATE=1 
external/local_config_cc/cc_wrapper.sh @bazel-out/darwin-opt-exec-50AE0418-ST-0d1fe7b00ffe/bin/mediapipe/graphs/face_detection/face_detection_mobile_cpu_binary_graph_text_to_binary_graph-2.params)
Configuration: e9670154d5af08fa52d86e0762a1381506511f62455c5fc774c6bd94d6701f1f
Execution platform: @local_execution_config_platform//:platform

Use --sandbox_debug to see verbose messages from the sandbox and retain the sandbox build root for debugging
stderr (/private/var/tmp/_bazel_timuribragimov/fedbca33a62f845c3a501d6b33f83488/execroot/mediapipe/bazel-out/_tmp/actions/stderr-724) 1953000 exceeds maximum size of --experimental_ui_max_stdouterr_bytes=1048576 bytes; skipping
Target //mediapipe/examples/ios/facedetectioncpu:FaceDetectionCpuApp failed to build
INFO: Elapsed time: 74.324s, Critical Path: 67.76s
INFO: 500 processes: 80 internal, 420 darwin-sandbox.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

Command to produce: bazel build mediapipe/examples/ios/facedetectioncpu:FaceDetectionCpuApp --verbose_failures --copt=-fembed-bitcode --apple_bitcode=embedded

Mediapipe v0.10.1. Xcode 14.2. I tried it on Intel iMac 2020 and on M1 Mac mini.
P.S. Also I tried older versions of Mediapipe, but result is the same.

Comment: same issue for me as well in iOS

Comment: Looks like this still [issue](https://github.com/google/mediapipe/issues/4239) in MediaPipe .